# Reward for daily login with rules

Tags: 7, rules, userpoints

I want to reward my users with 1 point for login every 24h.

Event: User has logged in

Condition: ??

Action: Reward points (I have a component)

I don't know how to reward once every 24 hours. how to?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [User Points](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) modules to manage the points, which has a very good API to integrate with custom modules.

Read this also [User Points Contributed modules](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib)